# MSCOMCTL.ocx missing Windows 10

Tags: vb6, windows-10, exe, mscomct2.ocx

I have some vb6 applications that i'm trying to move from Windows 7 to Windows 10. I have the .exe file, but when I tried to open it - it tells me that:

> C:\App_1\MSCOMCTL.OCX could not be loaded - Continue Loading Project?

I searched for this file in `C:\Windows\SysWow64` and found that the file is actually there as `Type: ActiveX Control`.

Any reason why I'm still getting the error?

Comment: I was pretty sure they ditched MSCOMCTL in Office 2010?

Comment: The apps were using 2007 - converting to 2013 now

Comment: Pretty interesting conversation over at the [VB Forum](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?706687-Windows-7-32-bit-MSCOMCTL-OCX-quot-could-not-be-loaded-quot) which includes several solutions which were used by various people.  Looks like the later answers point to IE10 as a possible issue with that OCX.

Comment: @JohnnyBones thanks

Comment: The ocx control should be in your Syswow64(if 64 bit pc) folder and not in the app folder and it need to be registered manually (common vb6 problem in Win7, 8 ,10). It seems you can see the file but it might not be registered. Run cmd in administrator mode, type "regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX. This should solve the problem.

Comment: thanks it did - pleas post as answer

Comment: To confirm what @Andre said. The [Microsoft documentation says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/ms788708.aspx) MSCOMCTL.OCX is supported on Windows 10 but you must distribute it yourself. That means you need to put the file on the machine and register it (regsvr32). You can do this manually or you can create an installation for your application.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use it in Excel ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The ocx control should be in your Syswow64 (if 64 bit pc) folder and not in the app folder, and it needs to be registered manually (common vb6 problem in Win7, 8 ,10).

It seems you can see the file, but it might not be registered.

Run cmd in administrator mode, type `regsvr32 C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX`.

This should solve the problem

Comment: If you're like me and couldn't find the OCX files from a reputable source in the first place, grab the Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 Service Pack 6 Cumulative Update (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7030). If the MSI install fails (it did for me), open the MSI as an archive in 7-Zip and extract whichever individual OCX files you need.