# mscomctl.ocx not found VB6

Tags: vb6

I am having quite a time with this slider control that uses mscomctl.ocx. On my development machine, I have deleted an old control in favor of a newer one (I was unable to get a copy of the old ocx file to satisfy the old slider requirement).

VB removed the old reference and I replaced it with Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0. I saved the project and compiled the exe. What I am getting when I transfer that exe to a different machine is `mscomctl.ocx` is not found.

Would I need to copy that ocx file over to the new machine and register it?

Comment: `Would I need to copy that ocx file over to the new machine and register it?` - Yes.

Comment: Thank you, GSerg. I'll try that and see what happens. Thank you again.

Comment: Just create a proper installation package.  Copying libraries willy-nilly is scary enough, randomly registering libraries manually is worse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSCOMCTL.ocx missing Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251880/mscomctl-ocx-missing-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

First Check your service pack version.
Install Service pack 6 on vb6. It will solve your issue.
If the problem exist then download MSCOMCTL.OCX file sp6 control from internet and copy and paste in windows/syswow64 folder. and register the file using command prompt. c/windows/syswow64 : regsvr32 MSCOMCTL.OCX
it will solve your error.

Otherwise right click on your project delete the object of MSCOMCTL.OCX control and reopen the project and select the component again.